# Change flying saucer header

Tags: java, pdf, xhtml, css, flying-saucer

Is it possible to change the header of a pdf page to the same name as the currently selected bookmark? I'm using flying saucer for my pdf generation. Could you include an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If possible, it would be better to obtain the source documents (from Publisher, Word, or wherever), modify them, and then publish to PDF.

Comment: Can't do that, these documents have to be dynamically generated.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me for flyingsaucer-r8 headers and footers: some bits may be unnecessary.

In my CSS:

```
@page {
 @bottom-center { content: element(footer); }
}
#footer {font-size: 90%; font-style: italic; position: running(footer); }
```

In my HTML:

```
<div id="footer">Footer contents</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me with flying saucer and headers.